# removing event in aws-lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am running a lambda function related with only database. I donot need any input from event. But handler function consists of event and context. If I remove the event and context, it shows error. Is it possible to remove these things? If yes, how?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/bin/lambda", line 187, in <module>
    cli()
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1060, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/bin/lambda", line 85, in invoke
    verbose=verbose,
  File "/home/preethi/newvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aws_lambda/aws_lambda.py", line 220, in invoke
    results = fn(event, None)
TypeError: handler() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Thank You.

Comment: You can't remove them, and even if you are currently under the impression that you don't need them (there is valuable debugging information in the context object), it's still unclear why you would try to remove them, rather than declare and then disregard them.  Can you explain this?

Comment: Because, my lambda runs in a cron and it all deals with the database. So I donot need any event and context.